# xsl:attribute-set not inheriting from xsl:attribute-set correctly

Tags: xslt

I can't seem to get inheritance to work with xsl:use-attribute-sets. Michael Kay says in Chapter 6. XSLT Elements > xsl:attribute-set - Pg. 269 that

> If this combination of attributes is also used repeatedly, it could be
>   defined as an attribute set in its own right, as:
>
> ```
> <xsl:attribute-set name="ruled-table" use-attribute-set="full-width-table"> 
>  <xsl:attribute name="border">2</xsl:attribute> 
>  <xsl:attribute name="rules">cols</xsl:attribute> 
> </xsl:attribute-set>
> ```

EDIT 1: USE-ATTRIBUTE-SET INSTEAD OF USE-ATTRIBUTE-SETS IS PROBABLY A TYPO IN THE BOOK; I AM USING *XSL:USE-ATTRIBUTE-SETS*

This doesn't work for me. In other words, in my current setup [XSLT 2.0 via Apache Cocoon, importing styles.xsl into mypdf.xsl] the result of

```
<table xsl:use-attribute-sets="ruled-table"> 
<tr>...</tr> 
</table>
```

would be the *set difference* of the attribute sets *ruled-table* and *full-width*, not the precedent-mediated *set union* of the two attribute sets. I only get the directly named attribute, not the parent attribute set of the attribute set named. I can simulate the effect by doing something like this:

```
<table xsl:use-attribute-sets="full-width-table ruled-table"> 
<tr>...</tr> 
</table>
```

It seems however that this should be unnecessary. Has anyone run across this problem? Here's styles.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs fo">

  <xsl:attribute-set name="fontstack">
    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">left</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">10pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-family">"TradeGothic-CondEighteen", "Trade Gothic Cond Eighteen", "Trade Gothic Condensed Eighteen", "Trade Gothic", "TradeGothic", "Trade-Gothic", "ArialNarrow", "Arial-Narrow", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="color">black</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <xsl:attribute-set name="headers" xsl:use-attribute-sets="fontstack">
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">18pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="space-after">7pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding">12pt</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <xsl:attribute-set name="h2" xsl:use-attribute-sets="headers">
    <xsl:attribute name="padding">5pt</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <xsl:attribute-set name="h3" xsl:use-attribute-sets="headers">
    <xsl:attribute name="padding">2pt</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues that may be causing your issues.

1.) You specified the attribute `use-attribute-set` in your first example for the [`xsl:attribute-set` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-sets), but it must be the plural `use-attribute-sets`:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="ruled-table" use-attribute-sets="full-width-table"> 
    <xsl:attribute name="border">2</xsl:attribute> 
    <xsl:attribute name="rules">cols</xsl:attribute> 
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

2.) In your stylesheet you are using the attributes `xsl:use-attribute-sets` on the [`xsl:attribute-set` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-sets) , but it needs to be the non-namespace qualified attribute `use-attribute-sets`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs fo">

    <xsl:attribute-set name="fontstack">
        <xsl:attribute name="text-align">left</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="font-size">10pt</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="font-family">"TradeGothic-CondEighteen", "Trade Gothic Cond Eighteen", "Trade Gothic Condensed Eighteen", "Trade Gothic", "TradeGothic", "Trade-Gothic", "ArialNarrow", "Arial-Narrow", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="color">black</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>

    <xsl:attribute-set name="headers" use-attribute-sets="fontstack">
        <xsl:attribute name="font-size">18pt</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="space-after">7pt</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="padding">12pt</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>

    <xsl:attribute-set name="h2" use-attribute-sets="headers">
        <xsl:attribute name="padding">5pt</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>

    <xsl:attribute-set name="h3" use-attribute-sets="headers">
        <xsl:attribute name="padding">2pt</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this - my issue is solved. Why is this second thing the case? Why does it need to be the non-namespace qualified attribute use-attribute-sets?

Comment: Because the language defines it that way; generally the XSLT elements itself are in the XSLT namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform`, the attributes defined on these elements are in no namespace. Attributes in the XSLT namespace are defined to be used on literal result elements, not on XSLT elements themselves.

Comment: Using an attribute in the xslt namespace on an element in the xslt namespace should give you an error, according to the spec. Such attributes should only be used on literal result elements.